# Should I buy a retired Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, shields, arduino-yun

I am a beginner who would like to buy an Arduino Yún (58 dollars).

It is retired so will I have any problem?

Else I can buy an Arduino Uno and an Arduino Yún Shield. But in this case I don't understand the difference between an **Arduino Uno + Arduino Yún Shield** and an **Arduino Uno + ESP8266 serial WIFI wireless module**.

Arduino Yún Shield: I can't find the price. I only found an Iduino.
[image: Arduino Yún Shield]

ESP8266 serial WIFI wireless module: 7 dollars.
[image: WiFi Module - ESP8266]

Comment: The yun has a coprocessor running a compact embedded linux distro, while the esp8266 is a simpler MCU running bare metal software or at most an RTOS.  Cost wise the latter clearly wins, though you seem to have been quoted quite a markup for it.  But your basic question is "primarily opinion based"

Comment: Yún has ethernet and USB. Which may or may not be interesting. You should get what you need, and only more if you can afford it. You could do an Arduino Uno  & ESP8266 & rasperry pi. For thuis combo there is an elaborate amount of tutorials, and will learn you about both microcontrollers and single board computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a board is retired, it may:
- get no support (never had support from Arduino zelf though)
- not be readily available.

Which may or may nog be a problem.
The biggest problemen with retired boards is that they often didn't sell very well.

So they may:
- target niche applications.
- not have a lot of people post tutorials on it.
- not have/get elaborate answers on Arduino.se

I believe you should only get something that fits your needs. 
Usually you van get away with an Uno, and since there are millions if (beginner) tutorials, i'd pick that as my first Arduino.

If you want to do anything more "pc-like" like USB, camera or a "server", my first pick would be a raspberry pi.
Also, since there are hundreds of tutorials.
You can choose to do it with a yún, and it may work, but you should check if there are tutorials/documentation for whatever you'd like to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

It is retired so will I have any problem?

It depends on what you want to do with your arduino. If you need a project that requires future support then dont buy a retired board. If you just want to do basic beginners stuff (like blinking LEDs, controlling motors, sending serial information wired or with an add on shield to send wireless information)-then any arduino can do these basic projects and probably at a cheaper price than 58 dollars.

Answer (score 1):

The question of the Arduino Yun being retired can be answered here:
http://www.arduino.org/forums/yun/retriered-boards-894?p=3495&hilit=Retired#p3495
At least regarding Arduino.org the answer is no. The Yun is **not** retired.

Comment: The Yun has also been recently moved from the retired section of the arduino.cc products page to the active products chart. I think this is a result of the dispute between .cc and .org being settled.